# how to query a Firestore DocumentReference field in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have Item collection it contains a reference named category

**as you can see**

[image]

I wanna search if category is equal to category reference it should show me all data with that category reference

here I am searching for the category

```dart
 finalReference({String? reference}) {
    String reference ='categories/${widget.firstDocs}/FirstCategories/$secondKey/SecondCategories/${snapData[index].id}'
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('items').where('category',isEqualTo: reference)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

but showing nothing

and when removing where method is shows me all kind of categories references

**and printing category like this:**

```dart
DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>(categories/7gGcmhHZBu7UbnrpPAov/FirstCategories/TyFolH2B1j0b8AUz55ZA/SecondCategories/vIeGUNBHZcNudEwMirQY)
```

**here I am showing data**

```dart
 StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        stream: CallData().finalReference(reference: widget.finalReference),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('snapshot Error:${snapshot.error}'));
          }
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            var snapData = snapshot.data!.docs;
            if (kDebugMode) {
              print(snapData.length);
            }
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapData.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                  if (kDebugMode) {
                    print('items is ${snapData[index].get('title')}');
                    print('items is ${snapData[index].get('category')}');
                  }
                  return Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      CategoryCard(
                        hasIcon: false,
                        mTitle: '${snapData[index].get('title')}',
                        mSubTitle: '${snapData[index].get('category')}',
                      ),
                      const Divider(),
                    ],
                  );
                });
          }

          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing a string value to the query, while you store a `DocumentReference`. Since the types are different, the values are never equal and you get no result.

To make it work, pass an actual `DocumentReference` to the query:

```
finalReference({String? reference}) {
  String reference ='categories/${widget.firstDocs}/FirstCategories/$secondKey/SecondCategories/${snapData[index].id}'
  return FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('items').where('category',isEqualTo: FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc(reference))
    .snapshots();
 }
```

Comment: How can do that?

Comment: the Firebase Firestore's reference data type is read as DocumentReference type in the flutter/dart project, so in order to check for their equality of them, you need to pass a DocumentReference with the path of which is a String in as the value equalsTo property

Comment: it is erroing type cost
String is not subtype of DocumentReference 
@Gwhyyy@Frank